# How to fix 'Dependency 'org.postgresql:postgresql:42.3.6' not found ' error?

Tags: postgresql, spring-boot

I am getting this error "Dependency 'org.postgresql:postgresql:42.3.6' not found " in my pom file. How do I fix it?

Here is the part that has an error:
`<dependency> <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId> <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId> <scope>runtime</scope> </dependency>`

I've tried reloading the project again, and the green leaf thingy does not even show on my properties file

Comment: could you share full `pom.xml` file ?